# Hiding of a ToolBar icon only for a specific Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, icons, toolbar

I am using an Activity which has 3 fragment.Back Arrow is visible because of using the following line. 
`android:parentActivityName=".Activity.MainActivity"`. But I need to hide this <--(Back Arrow) only for a particular fragment abd it has to be visible in another 2 fragment. What do I need to do?

[image]

Comment: try below answer @Parama Sudha

Comment: Yeah Sure..Let you know once I execute.

Comment: ok sure @Parama Sudha

Comment: Got Null Pointer Exception

Comment: wait i will check it in my project @Parama Sudha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this line of code in your fragment onCreateView() where you want to remove the back button

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

or

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code in your fragment:

```
    getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```